# Save property to variable and append it to DOM element

Tags: javascript

The code bellow does not work, obviously  objects can't be saved to variables in that manner!

```
function styleElement(aNode){
    var cssProperty; var cssValue;
    for(var c=0; c<2; c++){     
        cssProperty = c ? backgroundColor : color;
        cssValue = c ? 'blue' : '#fff';
        aNode.style.cssProperty = cssValue;
    }
```

Would somebody show me the right way?
10x and BR, Stephan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) and strings:

```
function styleElement(aNode){
    var cssProperty; var cssValue;
    for(var c=0; c<2; c++){     
        cssProperty = c ? "backgroundColor" : "color";
        cssValue = c ? 'blue' : '#fff';
        aNode.style[cssProperty] = cssValue;
    }
}
```